# Synchronizing static methods within abstract classes

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

Given that i have a singleton class

```
        abstract class Foo {
           private static Foo instance;

           public static synchronized Foo getInstance() {
            if(instance == null) {
               instance = new FooImpl(); 
            }

            return instance;
           }
        }
```

does this method lock on a Class object? do abstract classes even have Class objects?

Comment: That's not a static method, so no, it locks on the `this` reference. If it were static, then yes, it would lock on `Foo.class`. And it should be easy to verify that `Foo.class` exists, by doing something like `System.out.println(Foo.class)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `getInstance` method is a non-static method as in your code, you need to call it on a instance of `Foo` that would be a non-abstract subclass and the monitor object for the synchronized method would be that instance.

If you make it `synchronized` it will lock on the class object of the abstract class.

You can find details in the [Java language specification 17.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1)

Answer (score 1):

does this method lock on a Class object? -> yes it locks on a class Class Object

do abstract classes even have Class objects?->

In Java every object has lock.

We have 2 types of Locking mechanism in java -1) Object Level lock and 2) Class level lock.

if the synchronized  method is static then there would be class level lock and if the synchronized method is non static then it would be object level lock.

So as per your code the the method getInstance() locks on Foo.class object inspite of its abstract declared or not.